# having two input matrices in regression

Tags: python, theano, bayesian, pymc3

I wish to learn some coefficients of which some are sparse, and others are simply regularised as usual. The sparse part is done keeping Relevance Vector Machines in mind. My model is as follows:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    b0 = pm.Normal('b0',mu=0,sd=10)
    beta = pm.Normal('beta',mu=0,sd=30,shape = x_train.shape[1]) #normal coefficients

    #sparse weights
    alpha = pm.Gamma('alpha',1e-4,1e-4,shape = Phi_train.shape[1])
    beta_s = pm.Normal('beta_s',mu=0,tau=alpha,shape = Phi_train.shape[1]) #sparse betas

    # Likelihood - NOTE x_train and Phi_train are the two INPUT matrices
    mu = b0 + x_train*beta.T + Phi_train*beta_s.T 
    inv_sigma = pm.Gamma('sigma',1e-4,1e-4)
    y_est = pm.Normal('y_est', mu=mu, tau= inv_sigma, observed=y_train)
```

except that it doesnt seem to like the mu = b0... line. If I get rid of either `x_train*beta.T` or `Phi_train*beta_s.T` it compiles fine. Otherwise it complains of the following error: 
`ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[1] = 35, input[1].shape[1] = 500)`

So the sizes of the two matrices are: `(210042, 35)` and `(210042, 500)`. So am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you need the dot product of the data and coefficients, not elementwise multiplication: `x_train.dot(beta)` or similar

Comment: That did the trick. Do you want to put this as a solution so that I can accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above, you are multiplying the vector of coefficients and matrix of data element-wise. You should take their dot product instead. For example:

```
x_train.dot(beta)
```